# RPM spec patch application fails

Tags: linux, patch, rpmbuild

I have a spec file, which compiles fine without the patch:

```
build@SLES11SP4-185:~/rpmbuild/SPECS> cat testSoftware.spec
#
# This file and all modifications and additions to the pristine
# package are under the same license as the package itself.
#

# norootforbuild

Name:            testSoftware
Version:         1.0
Release:         2
Summary:         Demo - patch
Group:           Deployment
License:         GPLv2
Url:             www.dell.com
#PreReq:
#Provides:
#BuildRequires:
Source:          testSoftware.tar.gz
patch0:          test1.patch
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-build
AutoReqProv:    on

%description

Authors:
--------
    Raj Kumar
%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/testSoftware

install test1.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/testSoftware
install test2.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/testSoftware

%patch -P 0
%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT


%post
%postun

%files
/opt/testSoftware/test1.sh
/opt/testSoftware/test2.sh
%defattr(-,root,root,0755)
```

My SOURCES directory has the test1.patch and the *.tar.gz

```
build@SLES11SP4-185:~/rpmbuild/SOURCES> ls
testSoftware.tar.gz
test1.patch   testSoftware-1.0
```

Here is the test1.patch

```
build@SLES11SP4-185:~/rpmbuild/SOURCES> cat test1.patch
--- testSoftware-1.0/test1.sh   2016-08-20 04:49:19.000000000 -0400
+++ test1.sh    2016-08-20 05:33:45.000000000 -0400
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello - Test1
+Test1 - Test1 - patch
```

When i run the spec file, it fails:

```
build@SLES11SP4-185:~/rpmbuild/SPECS> rpmbuild -bb testSoftware.spec
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.10960
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf testSoftware-1.0
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/build/rpmbuild/SOURCES/testSoftware.tar.gz
+ tar -xf -
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd testSoftware-1.0
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 1001 = 0 ']'
++ /usr/bin/id -u
+ '[' 1001 = 0 ']'
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.10960
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ /bin/rm -rf /var/tmp/testSoftware-1.0-build
++ dirname /var/tmp/testSoftware-1.0-build
+ /bin/mkdir -p /var/tmp
+ /bin/mkdir /var/tmp/testSoftware-1.0-build
+ cd testSoftware-1.0
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.10960
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/build/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd testSoftware-1.0
+ mkdir -p /var/tmp/testSoftware-1.0-build/opt/testSoftware
+ install test1.sh /var/tmp/testSoftware-1.0-build/opt/testSoftware
+ install test2.sh /var/tmp/testSoftware-1.0-build/opt/testSoftware
+ %patch -P 0
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.10960: line 28: fg: no job control
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.10960 (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.10960 (%install)
```

Can someone tell me what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if we apply it after `%setup -q`.
Below is the modified spec file which works:

```
Name:            testSoftware
Version:         1.0
Release:         2
Summary:         Demo - patch
Group:           Deployment
License:         GPLv2
Url:             www.dell.com
#PreReq:
#Provides:
#BuildRequires:
Source:          testSoftware.tar.gz
Patch0:          test1.patch
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-build
AutoReqProv:    on

%description

Authors:
--------
    Raj Kumar
%prep
%setup -q
%patch -p0

%build

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/testSoftware

install test1.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/testSoftware
install test2.sh $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/testSoftware

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see it is not recognizing the `%patch` macro and sending that text exactly to the shell, which interprets the `%` as trying to refer to a background job-control process. That is because `%patch` is a `%build` step and is in the wrong section of the specfile (you have it in `%install`).

Move it to `%build` and you should be fine.

Comment: Still the same error, even if i move the `%patch` under `%build` or even if i move `%patch -p0` under the same.

Comment: That's strange. Make sure there is whitespace above it; I've seen RPM sometimes misinterpret things as part of a description or something. Maybe capitalize the `Patch:` field, just in case (grasping at straws now)?

Comment: I capitalised `Patch0: test1.patch` and also added a white space between `%build` and `%patch` still same issue. In between i always run it everytime as `rpmbuild -bb testSoftware_patch.spec` (Tried `%patch` as `%Patch` as well, with no luck.

Comment: I added my answer, it works if we put it in setup section, not build

Comment: LOL oops. I was half right - `%install` wasn't the place to put it.